# cv2 module not found when when auto-launching python script inside a docker image

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, opencv, dockerfile

I need to auto-launch my script - `test.py` when I run the image `test_image:latest`. This image has all the libraries installed and even the python script. I tried three ways of auto-launching it
but always got  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'` only for cv2. Others are working fine.

I have a docker image which has libraries installed like cv2, skimage, sklearn, numpy, etc. I have a test application which just imports these libraries and prints their versions.

```
import time
import json
import numpy as np
import skimage
import sklearn
import cv2

print("json -- version: {}".format(json.__version__))
print("np -- version: {}".format(np.__version__))
print("skimage -- version: {}".format(skimage.__version__))
print("sklearn -- version: {}".format(sklearn.__version__))
print("cv2 -- version: {}".format(cv2.__version__))
```

If I run the docker image in interactive mode and run the above script inside the container of the image using -

```
python3 test.py
```

The application runs fine.
Even if I run a python interpreter inside the container of the image -

```
python3
>>> import cv2
cv2.__version__
```

It still runs fine.

But when I try to auto-launch this script using `docker run -it test_image:latest test.py` It throws an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`

Even if I build the docker image to autolaunch the script using `CMD ['python3', './test.py']` and then run the image, it still throws the same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`.

All other libraries are running fine. Using docker-compose also gave same error

How do I solve this? (Basically I need to auto-launch my script when I run the image)

Comment: maybe you have two `python3` and maybe try `/full/path/to/python3`. If code works when you run manually `python3` and `import cv2` then try `import sys` `print( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python3` for working `python3`

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include details about how exactly you're building the Docker image and running the container?  It seems like the Dockerfile for `test_image` might have some key information for debugging this.